Composable template instead of XML template
I just started app development with kotlin and I started learning from yt but when I create a empty activity in android studio it creates templates having composable functions but I want to create ui with XML not compose what can I do ?
I am expecting a XML template where no composable functions defined

Aside: I'm not an Android programmer, but I'm pretty sure Jetpack Compose is the more modern approach. Instead of relying on random YouTube videos, I suggest you refer to the official documentation and embrace modern standards. Learning XML layouts in 2024 isn't a great strategy.


when creating a new project simply select the Empty Views Activity, it will create an XML project (with no compose dependencies), so if you want to add Composables you will have to add:

compose depedencies
additional blocks like composeOptions and buildFeatures in the app module's build.gradle(.kts)

you can also select the "Empty Activity" with the compose icon (next to "No Activity) and then add an XML activity like so:

